# c++ system fails to create child

Tags: c++, linux, shell

In order to run some command under linux from a `c++` program, I use the
`system` command.The whole code is relatively big but basically it loads some
binary files, reads them, creates some other binary and text files then run
`system` commands on text files.

For instance, is extracts binary data, analyse them and saves the output in a
text file. This text file is then processed by `gnuplot` to created some plot.

To run the `gnuplot` command I use something like `system("gnuplot -e
script.gp")`. This works fine for most of the binary files I have to analyse.
But for some reason, I have a few files that are problematic because once they
are loaded, `system(NULL)` returns `0` and `system("gnuplot -e script.gp")`
returns `-1`

`man system` doesn't explain why could happen. It just says that

- If command is NULL, then a nonzero value if a shell is available, or 0 if no
  shell is available.
- If command is NULL, then system() returns a status indicating whether a shell
  is available on the system
- If a child process could not be created, or its status could not be
  retrieved, the return value is -1

My question is the following : why does `system(NULL)` returns `0` (meaning no shell is available)?

NOTE 1: the binary files I load are heavy, when loaded they use <30% of the RAM
and one of the problematic files even requires <60%. I wonder if this could
ruin `system`

NOTE 2: the code runs on my local computer (with its local libraries) and loads
binary data that are accessed via `sshfs` on a cluster. `man system` says that
using a program with `set-user-ID` or `set-group-ID` privileges is dangerous. I
don't understand what it means. (if I do `ls -l myprog`, I get `-rwxr-xr-x`
permissions, but if I do `ls directory_containing_data_on_the_cluster`, I get
`drwxr-sr-x` which as a `s`)

## EDIT

After some more research, I found the probable cause [see](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32892908/c-system-call-raises-enomem)

Comment: What do you mean by `status(NULL)`? Please post your actual code rather than a description of it.

Comment: @Barmar, sorry typo, I meant `system(NULL)`

Comment: The `set-uid` and `set-gid` flags on a directory have totally different meaning, nothing to do with running a program with `set-user-ID`.

Comment: Check `/var/log/syslog` to see if an error is being reported when you get these errors. You could be running out of processes.

Comment: @Barmar, there's nothing in `/var/log/syslog` but your comment gave me the idea to check for memory, it seems that `errno` is set to `ENOMEM`. I will need to investigate further

Comment: That would explain why it's getting an error when you try to do the large plot. It doesn't explain why it's failing when you use `system(NULL)`, unless you have a bunch of large processes already running and there isn't even enough memory to test for a shell.

Comment: I wonder if you can run `gnuplot -e script.gp` from a bash script without errors. This could help diagnose the problem. (I would prefer bash script to `system` call if possible anyway.)

Comment: @Barmar I created another post with a MWE, see the update in my question.