# c++ system() raises ENOMEM

Tags: c++, c++11, gdb, errno

This question is a [M(not)WE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_Working_Example) of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32849257/c-system-fails-to-create-child). I wrote a code that reproduces the error:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int *watch_errno = __errno_location();

int main(){
    std::vector<double> a(7e8,1);  // allocate a big chunk of memory
    std::cout<<std::system(NULL)<<std::endl;
}
```

It has to be compiled with `g++ -ggdb -std=c++11` (g++ 4.9 on a Debian). Note
that the `int *watch_errno` is useful only to allow gdb to watch `errno`.

When it is run under `gdb`, I get this :

```
(gdb) watch *watch_errno 
Hardware watchpoint 1: *watch_errno
(gdb) r
Starting program: /tmp/bug 
Hardware watchpoint 1: *watch_errno

Old value = <unreadable>
New value = 0
__static_initialization_and_destruction_0 (__initialize_p=1, __priority=65535) at bug.cpp:10
10      }
(gdb) c
Continuing.
Hardware watchpoint 1: *watch_errno

Old value = 0
New value = 12
0x00007ffff7252421 in do_system (line=line@entry=0x7ffff7372168 "exit 0") at ../sysdeps/posix/system.c:116
116     ../sysdeps/posix/system.c: No such file or directory.
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007ffff7252421 in do_system (line=line@entry=0x7ffff7372168 "exit 0") at ../sysdeps/posix/system.c:116
#1  0x00007ffff7252510 in __libc_system (line=<optimized out>) at ../sysdeps/posix/system.c:182
#2  0x0000000000400ad8 in main () at bug.cpp:9
(gdb) l
111     in ../sysdeps/posix/system.c
(gdb) c
Continuing.
0
[Inferior 1 (process 5210) exited normally]
```

For some reason `errno` is set to `ENOMEM` at line 9 which corresponds to the
`system()` call. Note that if the vector has a smaller size (I guess that it
depends on which computer you'll run the code), the code works fine and
`system(NULL)` returns 1 as it should when a shell is available.

Why is the flag `ENOMEM` raised?  Why isn't the code using the swap memory? Is this a bug?  Is there a workaround?  Would `popen` or `exec*` do the same? (I know, I should only ask one question per post, but all these question could be summarized by, "what is going on?")

As requested, here is the result of `ulimit -a`:

```
-t: cpu time (seconds)              unlimited
-f: file size (blocks)              unlimited
-d: data seg size (kbytes)          unlimited
-s: stack size (kbytes)             8192
-c: core file size (blocks)         0
-m: resident set size (kbytes)      unlimited
-u: processes                       30852
-n: file descriptors                65536
-l: locked-in-memory size (kbytes)  64
-v: address space (kbytes)          unlimited
-x: file locks                      unlimited
-i: pending signals                 30852
-q: bytes in POSIX msg queues       819200
-e: max nice                        0
-r: max rt priority                 0
-N 15:                              unlimited
```

and here the relevant part of `strace -f myprog`

```
mmap(NULL, 5600002048, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7faa98562000
rt_sigaction(SIGINT, {SIG_IGN, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x7fabe622b180}, {SIG_DFL, [], 0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGQUIT, {SIG_IGN, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x7fabe622b180}, {SIG_DFL, [], 0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, [CHLD], [], 8) = 0
clone(child_stack=0, flags=CLONE_PARENT_SETTID|SIGCHLD, parent_tidptr=0x7fff8797635c) = -1 ENOMEM (Cannot allocate memory)
rt_sigaction(SIGINT, {SIG_DFL, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x7fabe622b180}, NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGQUIT, {SIG_DFL, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x7fabe622b180}, NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, [], NULL, 8) = 0
fstat(1, {st_mode=S_IFCHR|0620, st_rdev=makedev(136, 1), ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fabe6fde000
write(1, "0\n", 20
)                      = 2
write(1, "8\n", 28
)                      = 2
munmap(0x7faa98562000, 5600002048)      = 0
```

here is the output of free:

```
           total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:       7915060    1668928    6246132      49576      34668    1135612
-/+ buffers/cache:     498648    7416412
Swap:      2928636          0    2928636
```

Comment: You should use [strace(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html) on your program.

Comment: Is this on a 64-bit platform?

Comment: @Michael, sorry, I updated the titl

Comment: @KerrekSB yes, on a 64-bit platform

Comment: Would you mind adding the output of `std::cout << sizeof(void*) << std::endl;`?

Comment: @KerrekSB, it returns 8. what does it mean ?

Comment: What about the ulimits?

Comment: how do I check the ulimits ?

Comment: Type `ulimit -a` on the command line.

Comment: "at line 9". Please elaborate. Before line 9 is executed or after? Hiw do you make sure?

Comment: @n.m. during the execution of `system(NULL)`

Comment: How do you know? Have you observed something during the call? At what point exactly did the value change?

Comment: How much virtual memory does your system have available before you run the program? Can you show us the output of the `free` command?

Comment: @MarkPlotnick, I updated my post to answer your question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `system()` function works by first creating a new copy of the process with `fork()` or similar (in Linux, this ends up in the `clone()` system call, as you show) and then, in the child process, calling `exec` to create a shell running the desired command.

The `fork()` call can fail if there is insufficient virtual memory for the new process (even though you intend to immediately replace it with a much smaller footprint, the kernel can't know that).  Some systems allow you to trade the ability to fork large processes for reduced guarantees that page faults may fail, with copy-on-write (`vfork()`) or memory overcommit (`/proc/sys/vm/overcommit_memory` and `/proc/sys/vm/overcommit_ratio`).

Note that the above applies equally to any library function that may create new processes - e.g. `popen()`.  Though not `exec()`, as that *replaces* the process and doesn't clone it.

If the provided mechanisms are inadequate for your use case, then you may need to implement your own `system()` replacement.  I recommend starting a child process early on (before you allocate lots of memory) whose sole job is to accept `NUL`-separated command lines on `stdin` and report exit status on `stdout`.

An outline of the latter solution in pseudo-code looks something like:

```
int request_fd[2];
int reply_fd[2];

pipe(request_fd);
pipe(reply_fd);

if (fork()) {
    /* in parent */
    close(request_fd[0]);
    close(reply_fd[1]);
} else {
    /* in child */
    close(request_fd[1]);
    close(reply_fd[0]);
    while (read(request_fd[0], command)) {
        int result = system(command);
        write(reply_fd[1], result);
    }
    exit();
}

// Important: don't allocate until after the fork()
std::vector<double> a(7e8,1);  // allocate a big chunk of memory

int my_system_replacement(const char* command) {
    write(request_fd[1], command);
    read(reply_fd[0], result);
    return result;
}
```

You'll want to add appropriate error checks throughout, by reference to the man pages.  And you might want to make it more object-oriented, and perhaps use iostreams for your read and write operations, etc.

Comment: thx for editing and answering my question. If I understand what your saying, as soon as the RAM is more than 50% full, the `system` call won't work because it will first try to copy the process and its allocated memory. You give me two solutions : write my own system command (can you point where I could find information on how to do that) or use `exec()`.

Comment: The `fork` will likely fail when the process is bigger than the remaining free _virtual_ memory (RAM + swap).  `exec` is the right call if it's really the last thing you want to do instead of exiting, otherwise you have the choice of adjusting the 'overcommit' tunables (if supported on your system) or implementing a worker child process.  I'll update my answer with a sketch of the latter solution.

Answer (score 0):

Your line

```
   std::vector<double> a(7e8,1);
```

is probably wrong. You are calling a constructor for [std::vector](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/vector/) which takes a vector size and an initializing element. The 7e8 is converted to a huge size (i.e. to 700000000 elements).

You might want to construct a two-element vector, so use

```
   std::vector<double> a{7e8,1};
```

And with your huge vector, [system(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/system.3.html) library function will call [fork(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html) system call which is failing with:

> ENOMEM `fork()` failed to allocate the necessary kernel structures
>                 because memory is tight.

Maybe you reached some limit, e.g. set by [setrlimit(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/setrlimit.2.html) somewhere else. 
Try `cat /proc/self/limits` to find them (on Linux).

Use [strace(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html) (e.g. as `strace -f yourprogram`) to find out what is happening; look around the `fork` or `clone` line...

BTW, [system(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/system.3.html) should return an error code on failure. You should test it. And you might want to call `system("echo here pid $$");` instead of `system(NULL);`

Comment: No, that's the point of my question... I create a huge vector to have a lot of memory allocated. This will be the cause of the `ENOMEM` flag when `system()` is called. For small vectors, the code runs fine.

Comment: If my phone/tablet/dishwasher didn't have 5GB of memory available for allocation, I'd be pretty upset, though.

Comment: @KerrekSB: your *dishwasher* has 5Gbyte? Mine has probably some cheap 8 bit microcontroller (so surely less than 1 megabyte) and it washes dishes as required.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: That's not very IoT! :-)

Comment: But it washes well (and probably is not remotely hackable), so why would I want it to be IoT ?

Comment: I followed your advice and posted the relevant part of `strace -f`. but I don't know how to interpret the output