# x64 Ubuntu buffer overflow hacking with return to libc method

Tags: linux, gdb, buffer-overflow, libc

I tried buffer overflow with return to libc along https://blog.techorganic.com/2015/04/21/64-bit-linux-stack-smashing-tutorial-part-2/ this site.

But I get error

```
__libc_system (line=0x7ffff7b9a58b "/bin/sh") at ../sysdeps/posix/system.c:179
179 ../sysdeps/posix/system.c: No such file or directory.
```

I want to know why I failed.

I have little difference result between site.

```
gdb-peda$ p system
$1 = {<text variable, no debug info>} 0x7ffff7a5ac40 <system>
```

Above is site's one

```
(gdb) p system
$1 = {<text variable, no debug info>} 0x7ffff7a53380 <__libc_system>
```

But my result is like this. Does this difference make failure?

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 for practice

Comment: try to see this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32892908/c-system-raises-enomem

Comment: I can't understand why that link is related with my question

Comment: ... system() function, is different from a system call